# How to remove items from "Open with ..." menu?

Tags: windows

In Windows, when I would like to open file without using the default program, I right-lick on the file and choose "Open with". A few of the listed programs in the "Open with" window do not even exist on my system. I would like to get rid of some of the programs on that list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of Windows are you running?

If you are using Windows XP or Vista, you can use this small application to edit your Open With Menu...

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/open_with_view.html

I figure it should also work with Windows 7 but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Works with win7 -just tried it

Comment: +1 for recommending Nirsoft, they have great software, one of my favorite software sites...see this...http://launcher.nirsoft.net/

Comment: I use Open++ very cool https://genuine-lamps.com/fr/windows/11850-open-shell-extension-adds-advanced-8216open-with8217-menu-in-windows.html

Answer (score 3):

[OpenWithView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/open_with_view.html), a freeware program, works on most Windows systems. See [here](http://malektips.com/openwithview-open-with-windows-dialog-box-manage.html) for a quick overview.

On Windows XP you can edit the list using Registry Editor. It is best to do this only if you are familiar with editing the registry, and you should consider backing up the registry before you begin.

1. Go to Start → Run (or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

   - Type in `regedit`
   - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or click **OK**
2. In the left pane of Registry Editor:

   - Navigate to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`
   - Expand the `FileExts` key. This should display one key for each extension which might have an "Open With" menu.
   - Expand the key corresponding to the extension you wish to edit. This should display the selected extension's `OpenWithList` subkey.
   - Select the `OpenWithList` subkey. The right pane of the registry editor should now display the selected extension's "Open With" menu entries.
3. In the right pane of the registry editor:

   - Right-click and select "Delete" on any entry you would like to remove.

I would go with the software as it covers more systems.

Comment: @Indrek - Thankyou for the edit

Comment: No problem! If you want to learn more about formatting posts on SuperUser, see http://superuser.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

I found another source for an answer to this. Here is the URL:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18119/remove-programs-from-open-with-menu-in-explorer/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).