# How do I delete items from the "how do you want to open the file?" context menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

A while back, I tried to open a file that I did not open yet. That's when the "how do you want to open this file?" menu appeared. None of the items in the default list or the extended list served the intended purpose, so I had to browse for the exact application I needed in order to open the file. Unfortunately, along the way, I ended up (accidentally) selecting a "README.html" document and now the document is an option in the menu.

[image]

My question is: how do I delete the "README.html" option from the context menu?

Comment: Short answer: it’s contained in the registry, OpenWith key, as documented by this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1303165/editing-the-open-with-menu-in-windows-10?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: how do I delete the "README.html" option from the
>   context menu?

You can either restore the default .java file association or you can navigate to
`Computer/HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.java\OpenWithProgids` and delete the extraneous entry.

You might have to also remove it from `Computer/HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.java\OpenWithList` also.

[image]

In order to delete it for the current user you would have to navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.java\OpenWithProgids` and perform the same steps.

[image]

You will have to reboot your machine in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: You can also delete the user key, if everything else fails, provided you export the key before you do so.