# How to fix .exe file associations on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, file-association

I know that there are **lot** of similar questions on this site, but I've looked at over 10 of those, as well as some other websites, and none of the solutions I found seemed to work.

In short, I was trying to make my c++ compiled executables open up in git bash, not a command prompt. I right clicked on my executable (without really thinking it through) and clicked `open with -> git bash` (the checkbox that says `Always use the selected program to open this type of file` was checked). Then all of the icons on my computer turned to modified git bash icons and I realized what I had done. I then changed the default program for executables to command prompt, but of course that didn't help. The problem is localized to my account on the computer.

Solutions I've tried:

- The solution at [How to repair a broken .EXE file association](https://superuser.com/questions/362827/how-to-repair-a-broken-exe-file-association)
- Both solutions at [Incorrect File association for .exe files in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/789298/incorrect-file-association-for-exe-files-in-windows)
- The solution at [How to fix .exe file association in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/427434/how-to-fix-exe-file-association-in-windows)
- Pasting the text from the page linked in the above solution
- Both of the solutions on [How to revert an accidental file association](https://superuser.com/questions/490421/how-to-revert-an-accidental-file-association)
- The first solution at https://windowsreport.com/exe-files-not-opening-windows-10/
- The top solution at https://windowsreport.com/exe-files-not-opening-windows-7/

None of them did anything. I've tried making a new account on my computer, and it did not have the issue. However, I don't want to switch account if I can avoid it as I have a lot of programs local to my account and most of the things in my path variable are also linked to my account.

Comment: You should verify a new account works, before, you exclude that from being a solution

Comment: [.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/1313222/how-do-i-delete-items-from-the-how-do-you-want-to-open-the-file-context-menu/1313248#1313248) key should exist.  What are the current values, edit, please don’t submit a comment.  You can also use [this](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html)

Comment: @Ramhound your link worked! Thank you -  I would not have found that link on my own! All of the programs in my task bar & desktop seem to work now. The first time I restarted after this, my icons were all messed up but I restarted again and they were all fixed.