# Removing specific app on open with more apps list not working

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I recently tried to open a .jar file with java.exe ((It was a dumb idea and I managed to open it btw)). However, thats not the problem now. The problem now is whenever I right click a .jar file to open with and click more apps, my OpenJDK Platform binary is on the list. How do I remove this?

[image: IMG:]

Solutions that I tried was removing .jar extension subkey openjdk inside openwithlist and edit the mrulist by following guides from [this guy](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18119/remove-programs-from-open-with-menu-in-explorer/). However when I restarted my PC and try to open with a .jar file to check whether the OpenJDK Platform Binary is removed from the more app list, it is still there. Anyone knows why?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I tried watching solutions like this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/how-to-remove-a-default-program-to-open-a-specific/7e5b32b0-7fc0-4f1e-b1b1-817b02f94999) but I don't know this is relevant for my case. And I didnt check use this program as default when I first try to open the .jar file using java.exe

Comment: search the reg with the filename of openjdk and see if it is a openwith key - be VERY CAREFUL while editing the registry...I am on a non windows computer so cant check now.

Comment: I ctrl+f and search for filename openjdk however im unsure if its a openwith key, can you verify wether this is a openwith key? here is the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/LUM2K6Q.png)

Comment: I can't. Your screenshot doesn't show relevant information. I would suggest you don't play with the registry if you are not familiar with it. Why does it bother you that the you have it on the list now? check [Edit Open With List](https://superuser.com/questions/1303165/editing-the-open-with-menu-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall my JDK and it removes from the app list.