# Win10: How to Change Number of Programs Lİsted in Open With Context Menu

Tags: windows-10

Is there any workaround to modify the number of items listed in Open With context menu? Is it possible to list them all?

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1303165/editing-the-open-with-menu-in-windows-10)

Comment: They are not exactly relevant to my question.